# Why do i have 2 specular folder for java installed in my Ubuntu?

Tags: java, update-manager

I have 2 specular folder for java.
One is : `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24` and the other is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun`.
Why 2 different folder containing (it seems) the same things, and which one will be upgraded from package manager?

Which one i have to set as my $JAVA_HOME?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java-6-sun folder is actually just a [symbolic link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man7/symlink.7.html) to the java-6-sun-1.6.0.24. It always points to the latest Java installation avaliable.

As for the $JAVA_HOME path, you should probably point this at the java-6-sun folder, as this always links to the latest Java folder.

Comment: Sure... i didn't realize that there is a symbolic link from java-6-sun. I was watching only the sub folders! Thanks :-)